# If input is filled in, write values on another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I couldn't come up with a proper title...

The thing is, if a user writes anything on the "Accompanying Person" field, the "Accompanying Person Price" field will be filled in with 260€ automatically.

I have no idea how to do it but I suppose jQuery must be used.

This is my html:

```
<li class="titulo_form">ACCOMPANYING PERSON</li>
<input class="input_reg" name="accompanying" type="text" required>

    (...)
    <tr>
       <td valign="middle"><label class="registration">Accompanying Person €</label></td>
       <td valign="middle"></td>
       <td valign="middle"><input class="input_form_reg" name="accompanying_price" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    (...)
```

Comment: Show what have you done, anything... it's very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will help you.

```
 HTML:

 <li class="titulo_form">ACCOMPANYING PERSON</li>
 <input class="input_reg" name="accompanying" type="text" id="input_reg" required>
 <table>
   <tr>
   <td valign="middle"><label class="registration">Accompanying Person €</label></td>
   <td valign="middle"></td>
   <td valign="middle"><input class="input_form_reg" id="input_form_reg"        name="accompanying_price" type="text"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#input_reg").on('keyup',function(){
          $('#input_form_reg').val(this.value);
      });
  });
```

Comment: It actually works but how can I do it so when the text is deleted the value goes back to 0€?

Comment: use tis  if(this.value.length>0)
          {
          $('#input_form_reg').val(this.value);
          }
          else
          {
              $('#input_form_reg').val('0€');
          }

Answer (score 1):

An approach with jQuery will be to set a 'onchange' listener to that input.
If the input changes the value then a function can be triggered as a callback, and this last one can modify the other input. 
Be aware when you do it as some 'on change' listener cannot work in some browser versions (I remember I had a few problems in the past with that in a select list), but it should be fine.

The code should be something like this:

```
$('#input1').on('change', function() {
    $('#input2').val('260€');
});
```

You should verify also if the value of the input1 is empty or not (if I'm deleting text, it counts as input1 changed), so it may not make sense with your problem to fill the other input in that case.